# PHPUnit Codeception in Laravel cannot find my class

Tags: laravel, namespaces, phpunit, codeception

I have a class I want to unit test:

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Validator;

class Foo() {}
```

This class uses the Validator class to check data consistency, etc.

This is my test class:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Foo as Foo;

class FooTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test {}
```

When I run my test I can instantiate Foo but the Validator class cannot be found:

Fatal error: Class 'Validator' not found in...

How do I get the test to "see" the Validator class? I have tried several things including a require_once, use statements, and changing namespaces, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I extended Laravel's TestCase class instead:

```
class FooTest extends TestCase
```